# Cracking sound when unplugging headphone or extrenal speakers

Tags: sound, dell, speakers, xps, audio-jack

So I've been having this cracking noise and not sure if its actually a Ubuntu issue or defected hardware, also have to mention there is no such issue using windows. Also, the cracking only happen in 1 speaker (right side near the audio outlet)

My laptop is dell xps L502x

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ubuntu "issue".

That said, it sounds more like Windows8 just has a workaround for this, because it is common in all audio hardware. When you unplug audio hardware, the current flows through whatever touches the contacts. Since the plug is moving, different poles contact different contacts and cause the popping sound. It's not a hardware defect, it just looks like Windows has a way of detecting when you unplug hardware quicker, so it can mute that effect. In Ubuntu it does the mute effect, but not in time to stop the cracking in that one channel.

Comment: i tried to mute it manually before unplugging but the issue still persists? should install realtek audio drivers for it?

Comment: No. Correction: it sounds like Windows may actually shut off the hardware. I wouldn't worry, the cracking sound is normal. There's nothing wrong with your computer.